# How to achieve Recursion in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

```
if(url.toUpperCase().indexOf("SKILL") != -1) {  
  $timeout(function () {    
    $("#ABC").click();    
  }, 500)   
}
```

I am using `$timeout` to click the skill button and load the grid on U-I . Above code is not loading the U-I, but if i increase the time from 500 to 2500 then code is working properly, but I don't want to increase the timeout. Is it possible to use recursion so my code would work without increasing timeout?

Comment: Make sure angular has loaded your page. Where exactly in your code do you add this?

Answer (score 0):

Set this condition inside document ready. Maybe javascript don't found the elements, because them must be loaded first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //here
});
```